# Can't archive iOS app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, archive

I am attempting to archive my app to submit it to the App Store. However, the "Archive" button is grayed out. I can't submit it. WHat am I doing wrong here? I am a member of the iOS Developer Program, I believe I have all necessary certificates and profiles, what am I doing wrong?? I have archived this app before, but made changes, so I want to rearchive it. Help!

Comment: Have you chosen "iOS Device" in the schemes when trying to Archive?

Comment: you can _Archive_ only when the target is a real device.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please choose the scheme as **iOS Device** instead of the Simulator. That's it.

[image]